# Table JOIN giving null results?

Tags: google-bigquery, e-commerce

I'm trying to join two pre-aggregated tables as per below. The key here is that I'm specifically trying to join in both a metric (product_views) and a dimension (device) by joining on the lowest common denominators and the aggregating up by product categories, which all have a 1-to-1 relationship, so that works just fine, but I either get the metric returned as a "null" or inflated. What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE
`Table X`
PARTITION BY
day
CLUSTER BY
Market_full,
category_A,
category_B,
category_C AS
SELECT
f.day,
f.transaction_start_date, # - I have two different dates, where this is the one I need to join against
f.Market_full,
f.category_A,
f.category_B,
f.category_C
SUM(f.revenue) AS revenue,
SUM(f.items_sold) AS items_sold,
a.device
SUM(a.product_views) AS product_views
            
FROM (
SELECT
day,
transaction_start_date,
Market_full,
category_A,
category_B,
category_C
order_no
item_no
SUM(f.revenue) AS revenue,            
    
FROM
`Table F`
GROUP BY
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8) f

FULL JOIN (
SELECT
Date,
Market,
category_A,
category_B,
category_C,
order_no,
item_no,
device,
SUM(Product_views) AS Product_views,
               
FROM
`Table B`
GROUP BY
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8) a
ON
f.transaction_start_date = DATE(a.Date)
AND f.Market_full = a.Market
AND CAST(f.order_no AS STRING) = CAST(a.order_no AS STRING) # - The Order No. is the lowest common denominator
AND CAST(f.item_no AS STRING) = CAST(a.item_no AS STRING) # - Followed by the Item No., AKA SKU
AND CAST(f.category_C AS STRING) = CAST(a.category_C AS STRING) # - Product Category C is then the lowest denominator, and has a simple 1-to-1 relationship with categories A and B.
GROUP BY
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
9
```

Comment: The metric which gets nulled is an integer, btw.

Comment: Are you sure you need a FULL JOIN? Depending on your use case, LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Unf. I get the "null" values from LEFT or INNER joins, and inflated values from FULL.